# How far can I make a wire go?

Tags: fallout-4

Simple question, how far can a wire go from a power source to any object in one line?

And/or are there any tricks (not mods) to make them go further?

Comment: I thought the distance the wire reaches depends on what kind of pole its being connected from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Longer Power Lines](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/2241/?) mod increases this value and its description lists the default:

`fWorkshopWireMaxLength – 1100`

I do not know the units, but that's the value.

Comment: Thankx but I specifically asked for "no mods"

Comment: You asked "How far can i make a wire go?" The answer from the vanilla game is `1100` units.

Comment: Ah i see, i did not fully understand your answer, my mistake. I will see if i can find the units

Comment: Some googling led me to the following: In Fallout 3 and Oblivion, 70 units are 1 meter. So 1100 units would be 15.7 meters. Haven't found anything directly for Fallout 4.

Answer (score 1):

There is an item called a [Power Conduit](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Contraptions_Workshop#Power) from thee Contraptions Workshop DLC that allows you to continue your network further throughout your settlement.

Without it though, you might need to set up multiple generators throughout your settlement, since the cables do only have a limited range (what that range is though, specifically, I can't exactly define).

Comment: Thx, but my question is specifically about the range :/

Answer (score 0):

I would create a fusion generator, then apply small electrical receptacles periodically so it looks nice and functions well. For the Castle and most other settlements, I prefer the wall mounted ones. When I say receptacles, I mean the round metal things that look like they have spikes on the end. Those are the most efficient.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "most efficient"? Range wise? material cost wise? other?

Comment: well, i mean more simple and pretty. Idk if it is more cost effective than anything else, but i do know its easier than building a generator every time the wire drops to far. Plus it saves room.

Comment: you can definitely build more power receptacles than generators.